# Ruby connection closed (DRb::DRbConnError)

Tags: ruby, dbm, drb

I am experiencing a really weird behaviour with Ruby DRb or maybe the problem is dbm. I am using the dbm database with a server, and a client that makes the requests via DRb.

Here's the method with the problem (the database connection is ok) and it is in the server:

```
def get id
    obj = nil
    db = DBM.open @name
    obj = db[id.to_s]
    db.close
    return obj
end
```

This line `obj = db[id.to_s]` returns the error `connection closed (DRb::DRbConnError)` in the client side.

The thing is if I do this `obj = db['1']` it works just fine ('1' is a key in the dbm). Why does this happen? What is wrong with `id`? Here's the call in the client side:

```
DRb.start_service
r = DRbObject.new_with_uri(SERVER_URI)
puts r.get '1'
```

Why am I getting this error? The same thing happens with this method:

```
def delete id
    db = DBM.open @name
    db.delete id
    db.close
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In [/lib/drb/drb.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/23ccbdf52188b78427f41d75b1a4b81959ac9876/lib/drb/drb.rb#L570), it looks like the connection closed error is raised when `sz.nil?` and `str.nil`.

```
raise(DRbConnError, 'connection closed') if sz.nil?

raise(DRbConnError, 'connection closed') if str.nil?
```

what does `obj = db[id.to_s]` return?

Comment: I also tried `obj = db[id.to_s]` before and I got the exact same error than just `id`, which is a string in the client side anyway. It doesn't return anything, just raises the error and the server stops

Comment: In the get_id method, if you add a `p obj` between `obj = db[id.to_s]` and `db.close`, what does it return?

Comment: nothing, the server crashes in the line `obj = db[id.to_s]` so anything after it won't happen

Answer (score 0):

Try patching your ruby to give you a little bit more details about the error on the server side of the relationship.

See: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/1260.

In my case it was an issue with declaring a `safe_level` and then some of the code I called ended up violating the security (i.e. making a "dangerous call).